# Complex summary table using gtsummary in R

Tags: r, datatable, gtsummary

I have selected a few columns within the data set and I want to make a table by using gtsummary. I have come across some issues and not sure how to make it work.

Part of the reproducible data are here

```
structure(list(country = c("SGP", "JPN", "THA", "CHN", "JPN", 
"CHN", "CHN", "JPN", "JPN", "JPN"), Final_Medal = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "GOLD", NA, NA, NA, NA), Success = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And it looks like this :

```
country Final_Medal Success
SGP     NA          0
JPN     NA          0
THA     NA          0
```

Final_Medal contain NA, GOLD, SILVER and BRONZE
Success contains 0 and 1
All I want for the output is to group by country and count number of medal and success for each country.

Desire output:

```
Country  GOLD  Silver Bronze  Success   Total_Entry
SGP       5      2       10      17         50
JPN       4      3       5       12         60
CHN       5      2       6       13         60
```

Success will only count 1 and Total_Entry I want it to be included doesn't matter if it is 0 or 1

I have a code that look like this but it does't work and am not sure what needs to be done.

```
library(gtsummary)

example%>%tbl_summary(
  by = country,
  missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
) %>% 
  bold_labels()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do the aggregation in `dplyr` and use `gt`/`gtsummary` for display purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(Gold = sum(Final_Medal == 'GOLD', na.rm = TRUE), 
            Silver = sum(Final_Medal == 'SILVER', na.rm = TRUE), 
            Bronze = sum(Final_Medal == 'BRONZE', na.rm = TRUE), 
            Success = sum(Success), 
            Total_Entry = n()) %>%
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: apon reading the gt package, how do you sort the order in the table? Say according to the Total Entry?

Comment: After `summarise` you can add `arrange(desc(Total_Entry)) %>%`